How can I use LTspice to find Vmpp and Impp in a PV module IV curve?
I'm trying to find the PV parameters of a PV module IV curve with the following script:
.measure Isc find I(V1) when V1=0
.measure Voc find V1 when I(V1)=0
.measure Pmpp max(I(V1)*V1)
.measure Impp find I(V1) when (I(V1)*V1)=max(I(V1)*V1)
.measure Vmpp find V1 when (I(V1)*V1)=max(I(V1)*V1) 

The schematic is:

For the first three and the last one, it works fine. For Impp parameter, I get:
Measurement "impp" FAIL'ed

If I replace max(I(V1)*V1) by the Pmpp value, for example 215 W, it works but it is not convenient.
Could you help me to find my mistake?

Added:
I'm not sure I understood (or I should say I'm sure I didn't understand) Ste Kulov's advice.
I modified the schematic in this way:

and the .measure command like this:
.measure Impp find I(V1) when (I(V1)*V(out))=max(I(V1)*V(out))

but I still have an error in the log:
Measurement "impp" FAIL'ed

In fact I don't understand the need of the out label as the command below works fine:
.measure Pmpp max(I(V1)*V1)


Added:
Here is a solution to my problem: just replace
(I(V1)*V1)=max(I(V1)*V1)

by
(I(V1)*V1)=Pmpp

for Impp and Vmpp.
If you still have a "failed" message, it can be fixed by decreasing the step of the voltage sweep.

I think your syntax might just be wrong. It’s hard to assist without seeing your schematic, but for voltages you should label the node (shortcut key F4) and then to reference a voltage you use V(label) in your expressions. Using V1 directly, which I assume is the reference designator of a voltage source, doesn’t work for voltages.

Hello, I added the schematic. As you may guess, it's not from me (as I'm very new to ltspice) and I may have introduced mistakes. I hope it helps to detail your answer (it will be appreciated).

I'm not sure I understood (or I should say I'm sure I didn't understand) Ste Kulov's advice.
I modified the schematic in this way: Modified schematic with out node  and the .measure command like this: .measure Impp find I(V1) when (I(V1)*V(out))=max(I(V1)*V(out)) but I still have an error in the log: Measurement "impp" FAIL'ed In fact I don't understand the need of the out label as the command below works fine: .measure Pmpp max(I(V1)*V1) Thanks for your help.
Have a nice day.

@Newb'Rn I'm sorry tat the comment conversion messed up your formatting. Sadly, the site does not allow answers to be question extensions. I'm about to add your answer into your question. Please edit as you see fit. Note that questions must always retain the original question and not morph it wit time.

No problem, Russell. The mistake is mine. I added again the two pictures. I think it is now ok.

@Newb'R  Would you please add that new material as an answer to your own question.  Slightly more detail would be good if possible.  [As a bonus you get rep for any upvotes on your answer :-)

From the LTspice manual on .MEASURE

When testing a condition such as "when  = " you will
want the condition to go through the equality, not just meet it. This
relates to the fact that floating point equality should never be
required due to the finite precession used in storing numbers.

Can you verify that your equation is creating a number like 215 W? If so, maybe include a minus 1 to satisfy the above situation from the manual?
EDIT:  I'll leave my post for others whom may run into this particular math issue, but I think the comment by @Ste Kulov is the answer to your issue.

In fact, with the schematic added to my post, it works with 215 W or with 231.523 W (which is the true power with the given parameters). I don' know if it changes something to your answer.
